# Confused about address being referenced

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, register, address

```
lea     ebp, dword_403638
lea     ebx, [ebp-4]
mov     edi, ss:[ebx]
```

I understand the first instruction setting ebp to the address of the byte sequence. What I don't understand is what ebx will then be set to. And since ebx is being treated as an address on the stack, will edi refer to an address as well

```
dword_403638    dd 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand the first instruction setting ebp to the address of the byte sequence.

Correct.

`lea ebx, [ebp - 4]` will set `ebx` to `ebp - 4`. On the other hand, `mov edi, ss:[ebx]` will move (copy) the data stored at stack at address `ebx` to `edi` register.